# Create intermediate version from feature branch in git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

My app is currently at version 4.10 (git master branch). I have been working for a year on a new major version 5 with lots of new features. These include refactoring of the database which I would like to get out into production sooner than the full release of version 5. This can be achieved quite easily by creating a new branch, 4.11, and deleting the files with the new UI features and changing 3-4 files that refer to these files.

However, then I am in the situation where v4.11 is a branch of v5. I know that I will need to release at least v4.12 and maybe v4.13 before v5 is released.

I'm totally confused as to where the development of v4.12 should take place. I can't do it in the v4.11 branch and merge back to v5, because then all the deletions will also be applied to v5. And if I do it in the v5 branch and merge into v4.11, the further development of v5 will also follow along.

In hindsight I should have realized that the database refactoring should have been done on a feature branch from the v4.10 master, but that is too late.

Any advice?

Comment: why can't you create a v4.11 branch with selective changes from v5, and then get v4.12, v4.13 ...  from the same branch, and later rebase v5 to the latest version? you can probably cherry-pick specific commits from v5 to other branch.

Comment: Thanks! How would I create the v4.11 with selective changes from v5?

Comment: as I mentioned, you can cherry pick (`git cherrypick`) specific commits, there might be other ways also. Just read about how to cherrypick specific commits from 1 branch to other

Comment: Yes, I could cherrypick. But that seems like a last resort. I need to keep track of exactly what commits to cherrypick. It would be great if I can find a solution that allows me to do merges instead. That would be less error prone, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is obviously an over-simplified example. *cherry-picking* and *rebasing* may get tricky with conflicting changes.

Assuming your repo is in a state that looks somewhat like below:

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --all --oneline
* c8f1fa1 (HEAD -> master) another change that can go in v4.11
* d9a7458 more changes for v5
* 13764e4 for v5
* 7460f44 may go in v4.11
* c8e4ba5 (tag: v4.10) changes till 4.10
* f5f9a61 initial commit
```

Now go back to master and create another branch for v4.11

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git checkout -b v4.11
Switched to a new branch 'v4.11'
```

Here you would like to go back to the v4.10 tag, where the changes till v4.10 ware done:

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯ git reset --hard c8e4ba5
HEAD is now at c8e4ba5 changes till 4.10
```

Now you identify commit `c8f1fa1` and `7460f44` that can go in v4.11, and cherry pick them to the current branch (v4.11)

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯ git cherry-pick 7460f44
[v4.11 38f5bf2] may go in v4.11
 Date: Fri Apr 9 22:12:40 2021 +0530
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file_4
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯ git cherry-pick c8f1fa1
[v4.11 69a94e9] another change that can go in v4.11
 Date: Fri Apr 9 22:16:13 2021 +0530
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now your repo will look something like below:

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --all --oneline
* 69a94e9 (HEAD -> v4.11) another change that can go in v4.11
* 38f5bf2 may go in v4.11
| * c8f1fa1 (master) another change that can go in v4.11
| * d9a7458 more changes for v5
| * 13764e4 for v5
| * 7460f44 may go in v4.11
|/
* c8e4ba5 (tag: v4.10) changes till 4.10
* f5f9a61 initial commit
```

At this point if you are ready to release v4.11, just create a tag

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯git tag v4.11
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --all --oneline
* 69a94e9 (HEAD -> v4.11, tag: v4.11) another change that can go in v4.11
* 38f5bf2 may go in v4.11
| * c8f1fa1 (master) another change that can go in v4.11
| * d9a7458 more changes for v5
| * 13764e4 for v5
| * 7460f44 may go in v4.11
|/
* c8e4ba5 (tag: v4.10) changes till 4.10
* f5f9a61 initial commit
```

Now you can go back to your master branch and continue working for v5.0 and when you are ready with v5.0, create a tag there.

```
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ v4.11:git_example❯ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ echo "some more changes for v5" >> file_3
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git add file_3
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git commit -m"some more changes for v5"
[master 0f356bf] some more changes for v5
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git tag v5.0
dipto@ubuntu ⊷ master:git_example❯ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --all --oneline
* 0f356bf (HEAD -> master, tag: v5.0) some more changes for v5
* c8f1fa1 another change that can go in v4.11
* d9a7458 more changes for v5
* 13764e4 for v5
* 7460f44 may go in v4.11
| * 69a94e9 (tag: v4.11, v4.11) another change that can go in v4.11
| * 38f5bf2 may go in v4.11
|/
* c8e4ba5 (tag: v4.10) changes till 4.10
* f5f9a61 initial commit
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Only problem is that I have about 300 commits ahead of master in v5 branch. How do I know which to include? Also, some of these touch both files that I don’t want in v4.11 and files that I do want i v4.11. Is there any way to do this without cherrypicking?